# How do I do a redirect an Ajax Post in a Controller's Action Method?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax POST being sent to one of my Controller. e.g.

Enquiry > Index.

In the Index() Action, I return an ActionResult of JSON.

As I am doing login checks, I do an if statement and if the activeUser's session token is null, I do a

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Auth");
```

However, this is not redirecting properly but instead is returning the result in JSON which the browser complains about.

How do I set a redirect properly such that if the IF statement fails, it will go to the login page but otherwise it will return the JSON results that I require?

Comment: you would need to have the redirect done within the ajax success callback

Comment: The whole point of ajax calls is to stay on the same page. They do not redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return Json(new{data=true})
```

on the ajax success method

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'your url',
            data:your data
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    window.location.href="url";
                }
                else {
                     window.location.href="url";
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Comment: But suppose we want to pass some data too. how to achieve that. I mean along with the 'url' we want to pass some data too.

Comment: Just pass a data in Json format like data: { text : "hello"}.

Comment: I mean to say I want to pass data to the redirected page. I mean after the successful post. I want to pass some data to the window.location.href page

Comment: you can pass the data by appending to the url.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this :

Return a JSON result in both the cases, just return a false JSON reponse when your condition is false. In that way, your call will be returned to the AJAX on your view and then you can check the false value there and if matched, you can use javascript redirects to redirect to the appropriate view.

Hope this clears the idea that you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Controller, return true or false in JSON. Then in AJAX success, if true, set window.location to new URL.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Auth")';
```

Answer (score 0):

An ajax requested action will not let you redirect in this way.

In your error case, you can return an error value of some sort, and handle this case back in the jQuery in the view. This could be redirecting to an error page, displaying an error message etc.