# Problems with user verification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm checking if a user exists and then I will take him fowards him to main page if exists. 
  I have successfully invoked the main page action method but the front view doesn't change.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../login/login_req",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                _name: inf.user_name,
                _pass: inf.pass,
                _isadmin:inf.admin_or_not
            },

            complete: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

> Here is my controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    dbhelp dbh = new dbhelp();
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Login");
    }

    public ActionResult login_req(string _name,string _pass,bool _isadmin)
    {
        ret retu = new ret();
        retu.dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (_isadmin)
        {
           retu= dbh.data_table(string.Format( "select * from users where username='{0}' and password='{1}'",_name,_pass));
        }
        else {
            retu = dbh.data_table(string.Format("select * from employees where e_name='{0}' and e_password='{1}' ", _name, _pass));
        }

        if (retu.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }            
    }
}
```

**This is the controller that returns the main view that get executed successfully but the front view in browser does not change**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Do you reach the "return RedirectToAction.." line?

Also, ensure you use a correct user/pass combo ;)

Comment: yes i did but nothing happens it just get executed. No effect on front

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **SAME** page - ajax call cannot redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't return a `RedirectToAction` directly to Ajax. To achieve what you want you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431795/how-do-i-do-a-redirect-an-ajax-post-in-a-controllers-action-method).

Basically, you need to tell the js to call a redirect. There are many ways to do this depending on your specific needs.

Comment: i used   window.location.href = '../../home/index'; and worked <3 now i can handle him self

Comment: @Ricky, Using `location.href` to redirect in an ajax call is sheer stup.... DO NOT USE AJAX IF YOU WANT TO REDIRECT!

Comment: @StephenMuecke The question suggests to me that the redirect is conditional, and in that case, there's nothing stupid about it.

Comment: There is nothing conditional about the code in OP's question (which does not even compile anyway)

Comment: I have to use ajax for validation, and redirection is conditional